# Entity Framework -Update-Database- Does not create Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

Visual Studio 2013

I am trying to learn asp.net MVC over at PluralSight. I created a project(dll) called eManagr.Domain with the following classes:
Department / Employee / IDepartmentDatasource

Department.cs

```
public class Department
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Employee.cs

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

IDepartmentDataSource

```
public interface IDepartmentDataSource
{
    IQueryable<Employee> Employees { get; }
    IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; }
}
```

I created an infrastructure folder with the following file : DepartmentDb.cs

```
public class DepartmentDb : DbContext, IDepartmentDataSource
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Department> Departments {get; set;}

    IQueryable<Employee> IDepartmentDataSource.Employees
    {
        get { return Employees;  }
    }

    IQueryable<Department> IDepartmentDataSource.Departments
    {
        get { return Departments; }
    }
}
```

I then created another project using MVC 4 called eManager.Web with Internet Template during the creation of the project.

When running Enable-Migration it says I have two[eWeb.Domain , eWeb.Model.Users] which then I tell it Enable-Migration with the following command:

Enable-Migration -ContextTypeName DepartmentDb

which creates the migration folder and a file called Configurations.cs

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb context)
    {
        context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(t => t.Name,
            new Department() { Name="Engineering"},
            new Department() { Name = "Sales" },
            new Department() { Name = "Shipping" },
            new Department() { Name = "HR" }
            );
    }
```

EDIT -- Connection String from Web.Config --

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-eManager.Web-20140216202751;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-eManager.Web-20140216202751.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I run the following I get the following reponse:
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending code-based migrations.
Running Seed method.
PM>

After this runs, I suppose to see a database file in my App_Data but it does not exist and when I use SQL Server Object Explorer, the database is not created even though that is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you provide your connection string from Web.config?
Also, is there a Data Connection (Server Explorer -> Data Connections) named the same as your connection String?

I think, adding a parameter-less constructor to your DepartmentDb context class could solve your problem

```
public DepartmentDb ()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
```

Where name=DefaultConnection has to be your connection string name

Comment: Thanks .. I was banging my head and it was simple. What I am doing is based off a tutorial I am following and the person is doing it did not have the connection string in his class but it worked on his instance.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into something very similar.  I encountered it when I was going through the following ASP.NET MVC tutorial:
https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

In my case, the problem *seemed* to be that I already had a database table of that name.  I had gone through the tutorial partway previously about a month ago, but was interrupted and had to abort.  Even though I deleted the entire Project, it seemed that the database table name may have been retained.

I say seemed to be, because the problem disappeared with the following solution: after a 2nd delete of the project, I carefully substituted 'Contoso' for 'ContosoUniversity' in every relevant situation.

Before the problem was solved, I was repeatedly getting the (0x80131904-error) in the Package Manager Console when trying to update-database, and a notice that the mdf file could not be connected to the database.  However, when I checked the appropriate directory, the mdf file was not even being created.

FYI For beginning MVC-ers in Visual Studio 2012, I do recommend going through the following MVC tutorial before the one above.
https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4 
A MVC5 Visual Studio 2013 version is also available through that link.
The tutorial of the first paragraph makes a few jumps...

I could not have debugged the issue if I'd started with the EF5 tutorial as my first MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you enabled your migration in the correct way, have you run:
add-migration "give it a name"  ?
once this has been completed you will notice a new file in the migrations folder.
you wont be able to update database with out creating a new migration.